# error en matplotlib inline

Tags: python-3.x

Escribo el siguiente código:

```
% matplotlib inline
import sklearn.datasets 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot') #makes plots look pretty

# Generate a dataset and plot it
np.random.seed(0)
X, y = sklearn.datasets.make_moons(200, noise=0.2)
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], s=40, c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
```

de repente la consola me genera este error:

```
 "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\support vector\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/support vector/ABC.py"
  File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/support vector/ABC.py", line 1
    % matplotlib inline
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

¿cual sería una solución?

Comment: si quitas la linea `% matplotlib inline` tu código funciona?

Comment: si funciona , gracias.

Comment: deje una respuesta mas completa abajo.

Answer (score 1):

Si no estás utilizando IPython, solo comente o en su defecto elimine la línea, todo funcionará bien y se abrirá una ventana de trazado independiente si está ejecutando su script de Python desde la consola.

Si no está usando IPython, la primera línea de código de Python debe tener `% matplotlib inline` para que pueda ver cualquier trama.

La información fue extraída y traducida de las siguientes fuentes:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449549/python-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-matplotlib-inline?rq=1)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595766/matplotlib-line-magic-causes-syntaxerror-in-python-script)